# Splitting lines and retaining beginning and end on each newline

Tags: bash

I have a .txt with multiple lines looking like this :

```
> X 147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1),EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|516|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185081.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|537|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185075.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|586|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185082.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|611|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185076.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|632|FMR1||CODING|NM_002024.5|5|1) NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
> X 147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1),EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|516|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185081.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|537|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185075.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|586|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185082.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|611|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185076.1|5|1),NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|632|FMR1||CODING|NM_002024.5|5|1) NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
```

Each field is tab-separated and the fourth one contains multiple informations separated by a comma.
I know I can split it with `tr , '\n'` giving this :

```
X   147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1)
EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|516|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185081.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|537|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185075.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|586|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185082.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|611|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185076.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|632|FMR1||CODING|NM_002024.5|5|1) NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1)
EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|516|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185081.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|537|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185075.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|586|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185082.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|611|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185076.1|5|1)
NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|632|FMR1||CODING|NM_002024.5|5|1) NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
```

But what I would like to have would be this :

```
X   147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1) NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1) NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|516|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185081.1|5|1)  NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|537|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185075.1|5|1)  NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|586|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185082.1|5|1)  NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|611|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185076.1|5|1)  NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|632|FMR1||CODING|NM_002024.5|5|1) NA  11161.p1    NA  A/A 77  A/A 87  A/C 97  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1) NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1) NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|516|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185081.1|5|1)  NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|537|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185075.1|5|1)  NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|586|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185082.1|5|1)  NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|611|FMR1||CODING|NM_001185076.1|5|1)  NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
X   147010263   SNP NON_SYNONYMOUS_CODING(MODERATE|MISSENSE|aaA/aaC|K119N|632|FMR1||CODING|NM_002024.5|5|1) NA  NA  13829.p1    A/A 46  A/A 83  A/C 17  A/C 0
```

Please note that the beginning of the line (X 147010263, it's chromosomal positions) can also be different e.g. 3   41278119, 4 114275304

How would I be able to achieve this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in pure bash could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=$'\t' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 rest; do
    IFS=, read -r -a items <<< "$f4"
    for item in "${items[@]}"; do
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$f1" "$f2" "$f3" "$item" "$rest"
    done
done < input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

The outer `while` loop reads the lines until end-of-file is encountered. `IFS=$'\t'` instructs the `read` builtin to use the tab character as a field separator for the line being processed. The first four fields are assigned to the variables `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, and `f4`, respectively. The remaining fields and intervening tab characters (if any) are assigned to the variable `rest`  (Here, the variable names are not special. Any valid name could be used). The `-r` option is used in the `read` builtin so that backslash does not act as an escape character.

In the body of `while` loop, the `read` builtin reads the content of the variable `f4`, which stores the fourth field of the line being processed, splits it into fields using the `,` as the separator, and assigns the fields to sequential indices of to the array `items` (indicated by the `-a` option). The construct `command <<< string` is called `here string` (read the [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)).

The inner `for` loop (sometimes called *for-each* loop) processes each element of the array `items` sequentially. The `"${items[@]}"` expands each element of the array `items` to a separate field and that fields are assigned to the variable `item` sequentially. The `printf` builtin is similar to that of the C Standard Library.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. As I'm fairly new in bash, would you care to elaborate how this script works?

Comment: @EmilCioran Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk. Based on *note that the beginning of the line - - X 147010263 - -* I assumed that the records don't begin with `>`  like the sample data would suggest.

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"                                          # tab-delimitied
}
{
    n=split($4,a,/,/)                                    # split the 4th by commas
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                                    # for all comps of 4th
        for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)                               # and all fields
            printf "%s%s",(j==4?a[i]:$j),(j==NF?ORS:OFS) # output 
}' file
```

The beginning of the output:

```
X       147010263       SNP     EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033699.1|5|1) NA      11161.p1        NA      A/A     77      A/A     87      A/C     97      A/C     0
X       147010263       SNP     EXON(MODIFIER|||||FMR1||CODING|NR_033700.1|5|1) NA      11161.p1        NA      A/A     77      A/A     87      A/C     97      A/C     0
...
```